# Is there any way to use bulk_create with model formsets?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently using model formsets in my project.

The problem I find is that the app may have to show more than 50 forms on the same page, so saving them using the `.save()` method would generate more than 50 queries (one query for each form I'm going to save).

Since all forms have the same structure, it would be ideal to be able to save them with `bulk_create`, in such a way that only one query is generated, however the modelformset does not support `bulk_create`.

**Is there any way to save all the answers of the forms with only one query?**

The only thing that I can think of, is after validating the forms with `formset.is_valid()`, recover the `request.POST` and from there save with `bulk_create`.

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close to solution (But you can use `form.cleaned_data` also, not `QueryDict`). I will show you my implementation now (Which uses `bulk_create()` `Manager/QuerySet` method. This will help us to avoid a lot of **hits** on `DB`)

## forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ''' use same names for fields as you have in models.py '''
    name = forms.CharField()
    surname = forms.CharField()
```

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
        surname = models.CharField(max_length=55)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'person'
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.db import connection
from .models import Person
from .forms import MyForm

N = 3 # number of forms
def index(request):
    FormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, extra=N)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fs = FormSet(data=request.POST)
        if fs.is_valid():
            data_for_bulk = [Person(**field_dict) for field_dict in fs.cleaned_data] # this returns list and pass to bulk_create() method.
            Person.objects.bulk_create(data_for_bulk)
            # use connection.queries to make monitoring of sql queries during HTTP POST request.
            for query in connection.queries:
                print(query['sql'], '\n')
            return JsonResponse({'status_message': 'OK'})
    else:
        fs = FormSet()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': fs})
```

I hope, my solution will help you. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain more deeply this line `data_for_bulk = [Person(**field_dict) for field_dict in fs.cleaned_data]`. What do the ** mean?

Comment: It unpacks arguments and pass it to Person (Person.__init__) directly. ```d = {'field1': 'python', 'field2': 'django'} p = Person(**d) # This is same as Person(field1=d['field1'], field2='d['field2'])``` But if you prefer make pass arguments **explicitly**. I showed you all.

Comment: I already implemented a solution thanks to your answer :). One question: Do you know why besides the form fields, when you unpack the form there is an attribute that says `Id:None` in every form?

Comment: Where is ID: None ? in models or in forms ? what you are trying to print ?

Comment: In general, if model is not created(saved) .pk (id) attribute is equal of None. for example.
`user = User(language='python')`
`print(user.id, user.pk) # both will be None`
`user.save()`
`print(user.pk, user.id) # Now it has value`